# How to pass in 2 different length arrays as one training unit in Tensorflow?

Tags: arrays, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I am currently learning Tensorflow, and as part of this I'm building a neural network. As an input, it'll take a 42-length array and a 7-length array, and as output it'll put out a 7-length array or a single digit, it doesn't matter. I want to have 69 hidden layers.

Somehow, I need to train my Tensorflow model on a bunch of groups of 42-and-7-length arrays, but I'm not sure how to group them.

I currently have a large array like this:

```
myLargeArray = numpy.ndarray([[[42-length-array],[7-length-array]],[[42-length-array],[7-length-array]],[[42-length-array],[7-length-array]],[[42-length-array],[7-length-array]],[[42-length-array],[7-length-array]](and so on)]
```

How can I pass in each one of the grouped arrays into my Tensorflow model? I can't quite understand how because all of the input data in the Tensorflow tutorials is processed from CSVs.

Comment: Do you mean that `x` is `[42]` and `y` is `[7]`? Is `y` one-hot encoded?

Comment: @Maxim well, x is an array like [0,1,5,3,2, etc. until 42 length] and the seven-length array is one-hot encoded. But, both of those form the input and the solution that I'm training them on is just a single digit.

Comment: quick thought, i passed np arrays as shown in the example https://github.com/naveenkambham/Big5_Personality_Test_Using_SmartPhoneData/blob/master/Big5DeeperNetwork_KeepThisForProject.py BTW i used Keras a wrapper on top of tensorflow to use them.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to feed different arrays to *different* tensors. In this case, there's no need to combine the two into a single `myLargeArray`.

Here's an example [MNIST classifier](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/notebooks/2_BasicModels/logistic_regression.ipynb) that also recognizes a digit. It uses `x` of length `784` and `y` of length `10`, but the idea is the same.

```py
# None is for batch processing
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])   # one-hot encoded

[...]

batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y: batch_ys})
```

Arrays `batch_xs` and `batch_ys` have different size and both fed to the session. The result of the model is probability distribution of each digit, i.e., also of size `10`.